# Why can't we apply the Parallelogram Rule of vector addition for two parallel vectors?

Tags: vectors

My textbook says that we can't apply the Parallelogram Rule of vector addition for two parallel vectors. Why can't we apply the rule?

Comment: If you call the degenerate parallelogram where all four vertices a colinear, and the four interior angles are 0, 180, 0 and 180 degrees, still a "parallelogram", then you _can_ use the parallelogram rule for parallel (and antiparallel) vectors. Similarly, if you allow a side of a parallelogram to have length zero, then you _can_ use the parallelogram rule if one or both of the vectors are the zero vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parallelogram vector addition says that if two vectors have the same point as its tail or origin then consider them as two **adjacent** sides of a parallelogram and construct a parallelogram. And then the diagonal of that parallelogram (through the tail of those vectors ) will give you the direction of the resultant vector and for magnitude, you know the rules.

If you are given two parallel vectors, it is quite sure and obvious that you can't consider them as the **adjacent sides of a parallelogram** and hence tey get overlapped and you are left with just one vector whose magnitude is the algebraically added magnitude of the two vectors and pointing in the same direction.

[image]

You can't make a parallelogram (I am not talking about a degenerate parallelogram ) by taking two parallel sides as the **adjacent** sides since in that case, they would no longer be parallel to each other.

Hope it helps ☺️.

Comment: But why It is not possible to build a Parallelogram if two angles are respectively 0° and two angles are 180°? Since this kind of triangle is possible. Then, Triangle Rule will also not be applicable.But, Triangle Rule is applicaple in this case.

Comment: @Swapnil MZS how can you build a parallelogram by taking two parallel lines as the **adjacent** sides of a parallelogram ? If you really think you are right share the image you imagine .

Comment: Yup, I can imagine. Two adjacent lines will be overlapped when the angle is 0°. A triangle is possible if one of it's angle is 180°. Then why not for a parallelogram?

Comment: @Swapnil MZS okay you are saying that the sides will be overlapped . So now can you construct a parallelogram with just a single line (made of two overlapped lines )? Same is applicable when they are antiparallel .  Yo can't construct a parallelogram with a single side :)

Comment: @SwapnilMZS If you accept the answer, why not upvote it too?

Answer (score 0):

Because you cannot build a proper parallelogram from two collinear segments.

Comment: But why It is not possible to build a Parallelogram if two angles are respectively 0° and two angles are 180°? Since this kind of triangle is possible?

Comment: In fact depends on what you call a parallelogram :). What you describe could be called a "degenerate" parallelogram, and if you decide to include them, then there is no problem applying the parallelogram rule of vector addition to two parallel vectors

Answer (score 0):

If you call a Parallelogram with angles 0 a parallelogram , you still can use it, but most people just ad two parallel vectors as in  one line.

Answer (score 0):

If you call the degenerate parallelogram where all four vertices a colinear, and the four interior angles are 0, 180, 0 and 180 degrees, still a "parallelogram", then you *can* use the parallelogram rule for parallel (and antiparallel) vectors. Similarly, if you allow a side of a parallelogram to have length zero, then you *can* use the parallelogram rule if one or both of the vectors are the zero vector.

Jeppe Stig Nielsen's comment posted as answer